# HBase Get: Row values missing from Scanner results, all there with full key

Tags: c#, azure, get, hbase

I have a situation where values are missing from the rows returned by the scanner.

My key looks like this company_recordtype_recordid_childrecordtype_childrowid

the %id values are guids.

I am using C#, Azure HDInsights (HBase) and Microsoft.HBaseClient to do this work.

if I create a scanner like this

```
Scanner scanSettings = new Scanner()
{

    batch = 10,
    startRow = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myrowkey),
    endRow = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myrowkey + "~")
};
```

where myrowkey looks like companya_salesrecord_guid_receipt_ 
Start looks like that and End looks like companya_salesrecord_guid_receipt_guid(s) where guid(s) means that there are many receipts for that salesrecord (just a goofy example)

And if I want to look up all the receipts associated to that salesrecord it should bring back all the row values, or so I think.

Now each row has at minimum 8 columndata values, because they are required and I have verified that they exist. I also have a hive cover table over this and it shows them all, no partial weird rows. Only NULLS in HiveTable where values don't exist and full values where they do.

When I do the actual code run, I randomly get rows that only have say... 3 row values in them, while 99% of them are all 8 row values.

if I then take the full key to the row of data that has only partial values (like 3).. and use the exact same code, but qualify the entire key, I get all the values.

I am completely lost as how to resolve this... or even debug this, so any thoughts are truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misunderstood what `batch` parameter of a Scan means. The `batch` parameter sets how many *cells* the scan returns on each RPC call and it is usually used only when you have rows with a large number of columns. What you really wanted is the `caching` parameter — it controls how many *rows* the scan gets per one RPC.

Comment: You are a Christmas present come early haha!! Thanks so much that completely fixed it. I was so confused as to why random rows would have less values...